# Using Bootstrap 3.0 with unusual space appearing between <div> and <panel-groups>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a website using bootstrap in its col-md-8 frame. At first I placed a station picture with station name and icon on the image. Then the following contains each category of what it belongs, but finding there is a white block between them. I use development tool in Chrome 39 but cannot find what causes it. After deleting "stationContent", "stationBox", and "mask", the white block finally went gone. 
Now I use top attribute to control "panel-groups" as a temporary solution. Can someone explain? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Click [Demo on Google Drive via PhoneGap](https://bc970d6b742d093e19381cbfa1a153c8142716f7.googledrive.com/host/0B5_I1x5Qkr-DaWY4d3gzSVpNMVU/app/app.html#top)

Bellowing are my html code

```
    <div class="stationPhoto">
    </div>
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="bluredBackground"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stationBox">
    </div>
    <div class="stationContent">
      <h1>五塊厝</h1>
      <img src="img/icons/001.png">
    </div>  

<!-- content -->
<!-- where white block appears -->
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" style="background-color:#f2f2f2">
        <h4 class="panel-title">美食</h4>
      </div>
      </a>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="list-group">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#">Angoli Brunch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">豬肉蔥油餅</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CHACOMACA</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- another category -->
  </div>
```

Bellowing are my css code

```
.stationPhoto{
    background-image: url("img/spots/002.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -20px ;
}

.mask{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: -80px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bluredBackground{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -200%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("img/spots/002.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;  /* width must fit the column width */
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.stationBox{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    top: -160px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 80px;
}

.stationContent h1{
    color:#fff; 
    margin-left:40px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #000000;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.stationContent img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.stationContent{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -240px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.panel-group{
    position: relative;
}

footer{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: you have given position:relative and moved it thats the reason the space is visible

Comment: position:relative leaves the space and moves the content up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes `.mask`, `.stationBox` and `.stationContent` all have `position: relative`. This gives them the regular layout and then positions them, leaving a gap of whitespace.

Instead of giving these classes a `position: relative` try giving them a `position: absolute` to position them to the `.col-md-8` and give all classes a `top: 160px`.

Or even better, move these `<div>`'s inside the `.stationPhoto` (which gets a `position: relative`) and position them in regards to that.

Comment: That works! But I found the width of .mask goes beyond .col-md-8 at right side with its left side is in correct position, while giving position: absolute would fit .col-md-8. Setting width of .mask to 90% may work but is not the best solution. How can I solve this problem?
(You can click my demo via the link above)

Comment: You can try to fix it by setting a `left: 0`, `right: 0` & `margin: 0 15px` but it's probably an easier idea to put all elements for the station image inside a container and to put that one inside the `.col-md-8`.